# multichart line d3.js transform json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have this diagram:  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955
And I want change the file .tsv by .json

I change this method :

```
d3.json("data2.json", function(error, data) {
color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
return key !== "date";
});
```

And I change date format too a format json

this is my file example json:

[
{"date": 20111001,
"New York": 63.4
},
{"date": 20111002,
"New York": 58.0
},
{"date": "20111003",
"New York": 53.3
}
]

But now, dont show the diagram.
What is the problem?? I need change other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your json data is correctly formatted and evaluates to the same data structure as the tsv data, you shouldn't need to make any other change.

Comment: The json data is correct and structure the same, but it dont show nothing

Comment: Can you put up a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: You just need quotes around the dates. parseDate expects a string, not an int.